# Castor (Introspection) generated object not validaing mandatory tags are passed or not

Tags: castor

I have generated an java object through Castor (introspection)
While marshalling setting the mandatory tag as empty in generated xml not getting error.

what to do ?

Validating xml through Castor(intr)

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer: 
1) Compile  all files under descriptors generated for an XSD
2) In castor. properties mention one property org.exolab.castor.regexp=org.exolab.castor.util.SunRegExpEvaluator
3) Use validate() in your Marshalling /unMarshalling code

Then By default Castor will place  validation check on XML. while marshalling nad UnMarshalling.